# .htaccess RewriteRule multi-unknown variables?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting, uri

- simply my dir. files like

> ```
> owa-14.2.347.0-scripts-premium-flogon.bk.js
> owa-14.2.347.0-scripts-premium-flogon.js
> owa-14.2.347.0-themes-base-warn.png
> owa-14.2.347.0-themes-resources-favicon.ico
> owa-14.2.347.0-themes-resources-lgnbotl.gif
> owa-14.2.347.0-themes-resources-lgnbotm.gif
> owa-14.2.347.0-themes-resources-lgnbotr.gif
> owa-14.2.347.0-themes-resources-lgnexlogo.gif
> owa-14.2.347.0-themes-resources-lgnleft.gif
> owa-14.2.347.0-themes-resources-lgnright.gif
> owa-14.2.347.0-themes-resources-lgntopl.gif
> owa-14.2.347.0-themes-resources-lgntopm.gif
> owa-14.2.347.0-themes-resources-lgntopr.gif
> owa-14.2.347.0-themes-logon.bk.css
> owa-14.2.347.0-themes-logon.css
> owa-14.2.347.0-themes-owafont.bk.css
> owa-14.2.347.0-themes-owafont.css
> ```

- what is the correct rewriterule to explode my url slashes and replace them with '-'?
- btw the number of url vars unknown
- how could my url look like
- for owa-14.2.347.0-themes-owafont.css

  http://site.com/owa/14.2.347.0/themes/owafont.css (4 vars)
- for owa-14.2.347.0-themes-resources-lgntopr.gif

  http://site.com/owa/14.2.347.0/themes/resources/lgntopr.gif (5 vars)
- i cant determine the number of vars

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to over complicate such a simple mechanism ? Get rid of the slashes and make directories for your files. Simple.

If you are insistent on using slashes then you will need to use regular expressions, something like:

```
AliasMatch /(.*)\-(.*)\-(.*)\-(.*)\-(.*) /$1/$2/$3/$4/$5
```

But this can get messy and adds unnecessary complexity. I recommend you keep it simple and use directories.

Comment: what if the url more than 5 vars

Comment: i wanna a general rule bro ... can i use index.php for redirecting .. but i think it will recover the link

Comment: Yes you can, you can use a front controller

Comment: how i can redirect the index to the file without recover the real url